# Windows 10 HOME edition single idiom

Tags: windows-10

Control panel does no allow changing the display language of Win 10 HOME single edition. How can this be accomplished ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are going to need a little more information than that to be able to help you. Please be specific what "*does no allow changing*" means. Does it mean all options are greyed out? Or does it mean you make changes but they are not saved? If you need assistance on how to format your question, please read [ask].

Comment: If you cannot add another language pack to your installation then you don't have Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 2):

Windows **Single Language** Edition doesn't allow changing the [language as the name indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Regional_restrictions_and_variations). This is by design. You need the normal Windows Home Edition if you need a different language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the language you want to use before you can switch to it.

Bring up the Settings panel with <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and select `Time & language`, then click on `Region & language`. Now click on `Add a language` and chose the language you want.

After the installation is complete you should see your new language in the `Region & language` list. If you click on it, you can use the `Set as default` button to change the Windows language.

If you click on Options, you will see the list of installed keyboards, and if yours is not there, click on `Add a keyboard` to add it.

Comment: single language edition doesn't support adding new languages. I think he means this with "HOME single edition"

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I've never installed it, so I didn't realise that: I had assumed it gave you a single language to start with, without restricting the ability to supplement it with others. In that case, he will need to down-load the ISO of a multi-language edition and update his installation in situ, unless there is a registry patch to do it.

Comment: @AFH - There isn't.  He also would need an entirely different license key.  Single Language is language specific, and cannot be used to activate Windows 10 Home.